# Python colorama цвет input

Tags: python, colorama

Как сделать так, чтобы в python текст input был одного цвета, а вводимый текст был другого цвета?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
from colorama import init, Fore, Style

init()
print(Fore.GREEN + 'Введите что-нибудь: ' + Fore.YELLOW, end='')
text = input()
print(Style.RESET_ALL)
```

Предложение ввести что-нибудь будет выводиться зеленым, сам вводимый текст будет желтым.

Comment: спасибо большое!